# Div with 100% width, how to make it fill area?

Tags: width, media-queries, breakpoints, expand, fill

I have a 940px wide layout that I turn into a responsive layout once it gets below 940px.

The content I have doesn't respond well. It seems that if there is enough text in some of my divs, the divs span the width of my layout. If there's only a little bit of text, the div will go to the left of the page as per this example:

http://www.coflash.com/stuff/cssproblem.jpg

My question is... without giving divs an actual width, how can I assure thet they'll span the width of the browser no matter how much content they have? As soon as I set an actual width, I get scrollbars on my responsive site and it breaks everything :(

What exactly is the text doing that all of a sudden makes it fill the layout area?

Thank you for any help, and sorry I cannot provide a real world example, surely this is a common issue though.

Comment: Maybe `max-width`could be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

For that first make

```
 html, body{padding:0; margin:0}
```

then you can specify

```
  div{left:0; width:100%}
```

try this, it think this will help :) and reply if not done